# Highcharts Highstock How to add flags to chart drawn from embedded CSV data?

Tags: csv, highcharts, flags

I want to add flags to line or ohlc charts as shown here:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/flag-series

I don't understand how to apply the basic documentation shown here:

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.flags

This is the working snippet of html code without flags.

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<pre id="csv" style="display: none">
date,adj_high,adj_low
2018-02-27,180.48,178.16
2018-02-28,180.615,178.05
2018-03-01,179.775,172.66
2018-03-02,176.3,172.45
2018-03-05,177.74,174.52
2018-03-06,178.25,176.13
2018-03-07,175.85,174.27
2018-03-08,177.12,175.07
2018-03-09,180.0,177.39
2018-03-12,182.39,180.21
2018-03-13,183.5,179.24
2018-03-14,180.52,177.81
2018-03-15,180.24,178.0701
2018-03-16,179.12,177.62
2018-03-19,177.47,173.66
2018-03-20,176.8,174.94
2018-03-21,175.09,171.26
2018-03-22,172.68,168.6
2018-03-23,169.92,164.94
2018-03-26,173.1,166.44
2018-03-27,175.15,166.92
</pre>
<script>
Highcharts.stockChart('chart-container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Line Chart with Flags from CSV?'
    }, 
    data: {
           csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML 
    }
});
</script>
```

How do I add flags using csv data? Are there two ways to do this? Such as (1) add flag data to the existing csv structure; or (2) create a second csv data block to define flags inside a second tag <pre id="flags">?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the same csv and just add another column. Example below:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('chart-container', {
    ...,
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
        complete: function(options) {
            const flagSeries = options.series[2];
            flagSeries.data = flagSeries.data.filter(
                dataEl => dataEl[1]
            );
        }
    },
    series: [{}, {}, {
        type: 'flags',
        keys: ['x', 'title']
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8je3yfuc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.flags.keys

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/flag-series

Comment: Thank you for the answer showing flags on the zero point of the vertical axis. I could put all flags on the zero vertical axis but would like to locate flags for vertical points on the high line and for vertical points on the low line. If necessary, I would add a column with the set [z, h, l] to indicate the vertical position of the flag as zero, high (price point), or low (price point), or else I would make three series of flags. I may edit the question to clarify this challenge. I appreciate your answer and any further help you could offer with this challenge.

Comment: Hi @SystemTheory, Thanks for the more detailed description of the problem. I've prepared an improved script for you. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ues10k8q/

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek I marked this as the solution.

Comment: if it merits your attention - I have a further question. In your solution here https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ues10k8q/ the csv column headers are: date,adj_high,adj_low,flag. There is a fifth column in data with missing header that I would call the "pos" header. There are five csv columns and the Javascript refers to options.series[2],[3], and [4]. It is not clear to me how the five columns map to the option.series[#] to modify the code? I want to make a new csv headers DATE,INDICATOR1,ADJ-HIGH,ADJ-LOW,FLAG,POS. I can't see how csv headers map to option.series[#] in Javascript?

Comment: Hi @SystemTheory, You will get an answer to your question in the separate thread, that you created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76984484/highstock-highcharts-how-do-flag-positions-properly-map-to-csv-column-headers

Comment: Thanks. I look forward to your answer. I have been running some debug breakpoints in the browser console - but it is still not clear to me how the javascript code works in the context of the data module and the highcharts plot.