# Highstock highcharts - How do flag positions properly map to csv column/headers and to chart series items using options.series[#] in Javascript?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, highcharts

**Edit - Solution - Fixed Syntax Error!**

The question below has two answers expressed in the body and links to JSFiddle:

[Highcharts Highstock How to add flags to chart drawn from embedded CSV data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872553/highcharts-highstock-how-to-add-flags-to-chart-drawn-from-embedded-csv-data)

In each answer the csv data has several columns with headers. The Javascript, for putting flags on the Highstock chart, has code lines such as options.series[n] where n is an integer. The Javascript also has a number of series included within brackets under the "series" tag such as: {},{}, {type: flag}. My question is how do the csv columns explicitly map to the options.series[#] in Javascript code and also explicitly map to the items listed under the series tag?

In particular I want to modify the csv to include one or more indicator columns without disrupting the flags on the high and low columns. This goal is shown at the bottom.

---

This link https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8je3yfuc/ has relevant snippets shown below:

```
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">
date,adj_high,adj_low,flag
2018-02-27,180.48,178.16,flag1
</pre>

Highcharts.stockChart('chart-container', {
    ...,
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
        complete: function(options) {
            const flagSeries = options.series[2];
            flagSeries.data = flagSeries.data.filter(
                dataEl => dataEl[1]
            );
        }
    },
    series: [{}, {}, {
        type: 'flags',
        keys: ['x', 'title']
    }]
});
```

There are four csv headers (columns), option.series[1], and three series {},{}, { ... type: flags ... }. **Why is there a "2" in `option.series[2]`?**

---

This link https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ues10k8q/ has relevent snippets shown:

```
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">
date,adj_high,adj_low,flag
2018-02-27,180.48,178.16,flag1,0
2018-02-28,180.615,178.05
2018-03-01,179.775,172.66
2018-03-02,176.3,172.45
2018-03-05,177.74,174.52
2018-03-06,178.25,176.13
2018-03-07,175.85,174.27
2018-03-08,177.12,175.07
2018-03-09,180.0,177.39
2018-03-12,182.39,180.21,flag2,1
2018-03-13,183.5,179.24
2018-03-14,180.52,177.81
2018-03-15,180.24,178.0701
2018-03-16,179.12,177.62
2018-03-19,177.47,173.66,flag3,2
2018-03-20,176.8,174.94
2018-03-21,175.09,171.26
2018-03-22,172.68,168.6
2018-03-23,169.92,164.94
2018-03-26,173.1,166.44
2018-03-27,175.15,166.92
</pre>
Highcharts.stockChart('chart-container', {
    ...,
  data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
    complete: function(options) {
      const processedFlagData = {
        low: [],
        hight: [],
        none: []
      };

      const flagData = options.series[2].data.filter(
        dataEl => dataEl[1]
      );
      const positions = options.series[3].data.filter(
        dataEl => dataEl[1]
      );

      flagData.forEach(dataEl => {
        const matchedPos = positions.find(pos => pos[0] === dataEl[0]);

        if (!matchedPos) {
          processedFlagData.none.push(dataEl);
        } else if (matchedPos[1] === 1) {
          processedFlagData.low.push(dataEl);
        } else if (matchedPos[1] === 2) {
          processedFlagData.hight.push(dataEl);
        }
      });

      options.series[2].data = processedFlagData.none;
      options.series[3].name = 'flag on low';
      options.series[3].data = processedFlagData.low;
      options.series[4] = {
        name: 'flag on high'
      };
      options.series[4].data = processedFlagData.hight;
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  series: [{
    id: 'high'
  }, {
    id: 'low'
  }, {
    type: 'flags',
    keys: ['x', 'title']
  }, {
    type: 'flags',
    keys: ['x', 'title'],
    onSeries: 'high'
  }, {
    type: 'flags',
    keys: ['x', 'title'],
    onSeries: 'low'
  }]
});
```

There are five csv columns and five series items (two csv data and three flags). **How do the options.series 2, options.series 3, and options.series 4 map explicitly to csv columns and/or series items? I do not see where the index values 2,3, and 4 come from when writing custom code!**

---

I am trying to write Javascript which enables the addition of one or more indicators in the csv column headers without disrupting the rendering of flags. When I write derive code from the above examples all it renders is a blank chart or the three data lines with no flags!

```
date,indicator,adj_high,adj_low,flag,pos
2018-02-27,190,180.48,178.16,flag1,0
2018-02-28,190,180.615,178.05,NaN,NaN
2018-03-01,190,179.775,172.66
2018-03-02,188,176.3,172.45
2018-03-05,185,177.74,174.52
2018-03-06,187,178.25,176.13
2018-03-07,182,175.85,174.27
2018-03-08,184,177.12,175.07
2018-03-09,185,180.0,177.39
2018-03-12,187,182.39,180.21,Flag2,1
2018-03-13,190,183.5,179.24
2018-03-14,185,180.52,177.81
2018-03-15,185,180.24,178.0701
2018-03-16,188,179.12,177.62
2018-03-19,183,177.47,173.66,Flag3,2
2018-03-20,182,176.8,174.94
2018-03-21,180,175.09,171.26
2018-03-22,178,172.68,168.6
2018-03-23,175,169.92,164.94
2018-03-26,179,173.1,166.44
2018-03-27,185,175.15,166.92
```

---

---

---

**Further Research - Syntax Error!**

```
  series: [{
    color: '#000000', <!-- black -->
    lineColor: '#000000',
    lineWidth: 2
  }, {
    id: 'high',
    color: '#0000FF', <!-- blue -->
    lineColor: '#0000FF',
    lineWidth: 2
  }, {
    id: 'low',
    color: '#A9A9A9', <!-- gray -->
    lineColor: '#A9A9A9',
    lineWidth: 2
  }, {
    type: 'flags',
    keys: ['x', 'title']
  }, {
    type: 'flags',
    keys: ['x', 'title'],
    onSeries: 'high'
  }, {
    type: 'flags',
    keys: ['x', 'title'],
    onSeries: 'low'
  }]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The chart renders properly when I bump index numbers up by 1 each from 2-4, to 3-5, and when I fixed the syntax error in the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the first column is treated as `x` value for data in all series and every other column defines `y` value for next series.

So, for example, such row: `2018-02-27,180.48,178.16,flag1,0` will be converted to:

```
series: [{
  data: [{
    x: '2018-02-27',
    y: 180.48
  }]
}, {
  data: [{
    x: '2018-02-27',
    y: 178.16
  }]
}, {
  data: [{
    x: '2018-02-27',
    y: 'flag1'
  }]
}, {
  data: [{
    x: '2018-02-27',
    y: 0
  }]
}]
```

The filter in the `complete` callback is used to gid rid of undefined values for rows without data.

---

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping

Comment: **2018-02-27,180.48,178.16,flag1** The flag column maps to options.series[2] because the x column 2018-02-27 does not count, the first y column index is [0], and the next y column index is [1]? **2018-02-27,180.48,178.16,flag1,0**. Flag index is [2] and position index is [3]? **2018-02-27,190,180.48,178.16,flag1,0** Flag index is [3] and position index is [4]? These are the assumptions I made when writing code to show flags with indicator column but somehow either flags do not appear at all or blank page appears in the browser. So I still do not know how to map output series id: high, low, etc

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are partially correct, but please note that the fifth column is treated as a separate series by default, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/buzhv19d/ In this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ues10k8q/, the default behaviour is overwritten and the flag series (with indexes 2-4) are build custom.